# Install omniauth rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, omniauth

I have a rails 2.3.4 app that I'd like to extend with omniauth (0.1.5).  When I install omniauth gem using rvm and place require 'omniauth' in the config.rb file I get the following error:

`gem_original_require': no such file to load -- omniauth (MissingSourceFile)

The tutorials suggest using putting it in the gemfile but I am using rails 2.

When I 'gem list' omniauth is available however.

This has taken a couple of (hair-pulling) days and I am not sure how to proceed.

Am I placing the require in the correct place or is there somewhere else I could put it (aside form the obvious :-))?

Any ideas would be great....

**EDIT 1:** I tried config.gem "omniauth" in your environments.rb file and got 
/home/mcaulejj/explorer/config/environment.rb:10: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)

**EDIT 2:** Using RVM I updated all gems but I am still getting the same error.....

I'm exasperated at this point.

Cheers Slothihtype

Answer (score 1):

Try `config.gem "omniauth"` in your `environments.rb` file.

**EDIT**

As per comment,

try:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')
#insert the following here, in your config/environment.rb
if Gem::VERSION >= "1.3.6" 
    module Rails
        class GemDependency
            def requirement
                r = super
                (r == Gem::Requirement.default) ? nil : r
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @fareesh-vijayarangam cheers.  Did that and now getting.... `requirement': undefined local variable or method `version_requirements' for #<Rails::GemDependency:0x7fc111fb3630> (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Add `require 'oa-oauth'` in your environment.rb file